# Redirigir con SERVLET y JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Tengo un listado de pedidos, al hacer clic en uno veo el detalle de ese pedido y tengo un botón para marcarlo como ENTREGADO. Paso la id del pedido desde un jsp a un servlet y ahí hago el update (hasta aca funciona bien), pero después del update quiero que me lleve al jsp con el listado de pedidos, pero esto no ocurre.

DetallesPedido.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <c:set var="pedido" value="${pedido}"/>
        <c:if test="${pedido != null}">
            <div>
                <p><label>Código: </label> ${pedido.id}</p>
                <p><label>Descripción: </label> ${pedido.descripcion}</p>
                <p><label>Dirección: </label> ${pedido.direccion}</p>
                <p><label>Precio: </label> U$ ${pedido.precio}</p>
                <p><label>Fecha: </label> ${pedido.fechaHora}</p>
                <a class="btn btn-info" role="button" href="VerRutaServlet?id=${pedido.id}">Ver ruta de entrega</a>
                <a class="btn btn-info" role="button" href="PedidoEntregadoServlet?id=${pedido.id}">ENTREGADO</a>
            </div>
        </c:if>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

PedidoEntregadoServlet.java

```
@WebServlet(name = "PedidoEntregadoServlet", urlPatterns = {"/PedidoEntregadoServlet"})
public class PedidoEntregadoServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {


        String id = request.getParameter("id");
        Consulta cons;
        boolean funciono = false;
        try{
            cons = new Consulta("*", "pedidos");
            if (cons.actualizarPorId(Integer.parseInt(id), "estado = 'ENTREGADO'")){
                funciono = true;
            }
            if (funciono)
                request.getRequestDispatcher("/repartidores/Pedidos.jsp").forward(request, response);
        } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ConsultaPedidosServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex.getMessage());
        } 
    }
}
```

En la url me queda: http://localhost:8084/appRepartidores/PedidoEntregadoServlet?id=35

pero yo quiero que sea: http://localhost:8084/appRepartidores/ConsultaPedidosServlet, este es el que muestra todos los pedidos y funciona correctamente.

Comment: recibes algun error al redireccionar?

Comment: no as probrado con response.sendRedirect('consultaPedidosServlet')?

Comment: Hola, no no, solo me muestra la página en blanco.

Comment: @J.Castro no, voy a probar.

Comment: @J.Castro Gracias crack!, funciona impecable ahora.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tu código cambia `request.getRequestDispatcher("/repartidores/Pedidos.jsp").forward(request, response);` por esta funcion `response.sendRedirect('consultaPedidosServlet')` asi rediriges la petición hacia el JSP solicitado.